# Passing dynamic object to C# method changes return type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I created a [class that inherits `DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and want to create a static method that can create new instances with pre-determined properties (stored in the `Dictionary`).

```
public class CustomDynamic : DynamicObject
{
    protected Dictionary<string, object> InnerDictionary;

    public static T Create<T>(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary) where T : CustomDynamic , new()
    {
        return new T
        {
            InnerDictionary = dictionary
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dynamic d = new Dictionary<string, object>();

var realPlayer = CustomDynamic.Create<Player>(d as Dictionary<string, object>);
var dynaPlayer = CustomDynamic.Create<Player>(d);

realPlayer // Player type according to VS2013
dynaPlayer // dynamic type according to VS2013
```

Since there is only one method signature, why does passing in a dynamic return a dynamic object? Or is actually just Visual Studio 2013 getting confused?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because almost *any* operation involving a dynamic value is resolved dynamically at execution time. There are no exceptions made for cases where actually there's only one method present at compile-time; the language is simpler that way. (For certain calls, the compiler *does* perform enough resolution at compile-time to ensure that there is at least one method with a suitable number of parameters - this is specified in the C# 5 spec in section 7.5.4, but that doesn't affect the effective return type.)

From the C# 5 spec, section 7.6.5:

> An *invocation-expression* is dynamically bound if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - The *primary-expression* has compile-time type `dynamic`.
> - At least one argument of the optional *argument-list* has compile-time type `dynamic` and the *primary-expression* does not have a delegate type.
>
> In this case the compiler classifies the *invocation-expression* as a value of type `dynamic`. [...]

There are a *few* operations involving dynamic values which still have a non-dynamic overall type. For example:

- `d is Foo` is always `bool`
- `d as Foo` is always `Foo`
- `new Foo(d)` is always `Foo` even though the exact constructor to use is determined at execution time

But any method call is treated as having a return type of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 9):

It's how dynamic works. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

> Overload resolution occurs at run time instead of at compile time if one or more of the arguments in a method call have the type dynamic, or if the receiver of the method call is of type dynamic.

You might think that you don't have any additional overloads for your method but you might have. Compiler doesn't perform that check at compile time so that's why you see the type of `dynaPlayer` as dynamic instead of `Player`.